# How to add a tooltip to a cell in a jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tooltip, listener

I have a table where each row represents a picture. In the column Path I store its absolute path. The string being kinda long, I would like that when I hover the mouse over the specific cell, a tooltip should pop-up next to the mouse containing the information from the cell.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I assume you didn't write a custom `CellRenderer` for the path but just use the `DefaultTableCellRenderer`. You should subclass the `DefaultTableCellRenderer` and set the tooltip in the `getTableCellRendererComponent`. Then set the renderer for the column.

```
class PathCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                        JTable table, Object value,
                        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                        int row, int column) {
        JLabel c = (JLabel)super.getTableCellRendererComponent( /* params from above (table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column) */ );
        // This...
        String pathValue = <getYourPathValue>; // Could be value.toString()
        c.setToolTipText(pathValue);
        // ...OR this probably works in your case:
        c.setToolTipText(c.getText());
        return c;
    }
}

...
pathColumn.setCellRenderer(new PathCellRenderer()); // If your path is of specific class (e.g. java.io.File) you could set the renderer for that type
...
```

- [Oracle JTable tutorial on tooltips](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#celltooltip)

Comment: You can't call super.getTableCellRendererComponent.

Comment: @codenamezero Why not? You are aware that in the sample code I subclassed `DefaultTableCellRenderer` which has the method in a non-abstract fashion and is itself a `JLabel`?

Comment: there is a one argument in getTableCellRendererComponent() method as Object value. So here what is the value means? Is it row data or column data that we put tooltip

Comment: @chamzz.dot I am not sure I completely grasp your intention but I'll try. The renderer is used on single cells only. The `DefaultTableCellRenderer` *is* a `JLable` by hierarchy and is cast to this so all its methods can be used.

Comment: Ok I mean like this Hauke Ingmar Schmidt ,The value you pass to `getTableCellRendererComponent` method is importent here. Here the 2nd argument Object value is must be the value of your column. Then you can try with `JLabel cellComponent = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row,
        column);` and then `cellComponent.setToolTipText(value.toString());`

Comment: Cast to JLabel seems to much, just test the reference from super.getTableCellRenderer against JComponent and you're able to set the tip: `Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(); if ( c instanceof JComponent) { ((JComponent) c).setToolTipText("what you need");}`

Answer (score 50):

Just use below code while creation of JTable object.

```
JTable auditTable = new JTable(){

            //Implement table cell tool tips.           
            public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
                String tip = null;
                java.awt.Point p = e.getPoint();
                int rowIndex = rowAtPoint(p);
                int colIndex = columnAtPoint(p);

                try {
                    tip = getValueAt(rowIndex, colIndex).toString();
                } catch (RuntimeException e1) {
                    //catch null pointer exception if mouse is over an empty line
                }

                return tip;
            }
        };
```

Comment: Actually, I think it is more efficient than the accepted solution.

Comment: This might not work when we sort the table based on some column.

Comment: Use `getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(rowIndex)` and `getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(rowIndex)` to get the exact row from the model.

Comment: @NagendraVarma In the example, `JTable.getValueAt` is used which uses view indexes. The model indexes are only necessary if you use the model to look up values (i.e. `getModel( ).getValueAt`). So as the example is written, it will work when the table is sorted, or filtered, etc.

Comment: When I implement this sorting by clicking the column header stops working using a basic DefaultRowSorter.. After a day of debugging it appears the sort is happening, the current row highlight is changed, but the table is not redrawn. Upgrading from Java 11 to 19 did not make any difference. Is that a Java bug or is there something more that must be done? A basic subclass of JTable should inherit all that.

Answer (score 0):

You say you store an absolute path in a cell. You are probably using a `JLabel` for setting *absolute path string*. Suppose you have a label in your cell, use html tags for expressing tooltip content:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Bla bla");
label.setToolTipText("<html><p>information about cell</p></html>");
```

`setToolTipText()` can be used for some other Swing components if you are using something other than JLabel.

Comment: *"deffinetly nope"*  I wonder if @deporter understands that comment.  I sure don't. :(

Comment: please be a bit more precise: _have a label in your cell_ could be misleading (there shouldn't be components in cell, ever) Instead it's a label provided by a renderer as ... well .. rendering component :-)

Comment: It means I did not understand the comment.  If you did, please explain it to me.  What is being referred to in the negative?  What is 'nope'?