# How to set Javatable ToolTip

Tags: java, java-8, jtable, tooltip

I'm writing program in Java 8. I need to set different tooltips for headers and for column cells of the table. I'm using `javax.swing.JTable` table.

Comment: Which GUI-framework do you use? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The tooltip text for the cells and headers will come from the `TableCellRenderer` used to render said cells and headers

Comment: Sorry! I'm using javax.swing.JTable table.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121575/how-to-add-tooltip-on-jtable-to-show-cell-values-of-a-particular-column-on-mouse/13128181#13128181) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238676/tooltip-position-for-cell-in-jtable/31238769#31238769)

Comment: You may find these useful:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467093/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-a-cell-in-a-jtable

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332159/how-to-add-tooltips-to-jtables-rows